# Lightsail Wordpress Instance Restart Apache

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, apache, phpmyadmin

I am trying to import a sql file that exceeds the default file size in the `phpmyadmin` tool. So after some research, I discovered I needed to change some of the variables in the `php.ini`. Specifically the : `upload_max_filesize, memory_limit and post_max_size in the php.ini`. Easy enough, then I assumed I needed to restart the apache2 server and I did just that:

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
Unmonitored apache
Syntax OK
/opt/bitnami/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : httpd stopped
Syntax OK
/opt/bitnami/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : httpd started at port 80
Monitored apache`
```

However, the limit size did not change in the `phpmyadmin` tool. I also printed out the `phpinfo()` command to see if there are multiple versions of the `php.ini` file which there isn't. So now I am really stuck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The main php.ini file path :- /opt/bitnami/php/etc/php.ini

Comment: The question is not topic'ed correctly, but this answer definitely solved a very crucial problem I had. Kudos.